# do Carmo's proof of the Morse Index Theorem for geodesics: why is $I_t$ continuous in $t$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to understand the proof of the Morse Index Theorem for geodesics given in do Carmo's book on Riemannian Geometry, specifically the following excerpt from Chapter 11, page 246:

[image]

It's the final sentence that I can't quite figure out. Here's the situation:

We have a geodesic $\gamma \colon [0, a] \to M$, and for any $t \in (0, a)$, we consider the index form $I_t$, which is a quadratic form defined on the space $\mathcal V(0,t)$, the space of piecewise smooth vector fields along $\gamma|_{[0,t]}$ that vanish at the end points. The definition of $I_t$ is
$$ I_t (V, V) = -\int_0^t \langle V'' + R(V, \gamma') \gamma', V \rangle - \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \langle V'(t_i^+) - V'(t_i^-), V(t_i) \rangle, \qquad (\star) $$
where $V'$ denotes the covariant derivative of $V$ along $\gamma$, and similarly $V''$ is the covariant derivative of $V'$ along $\gamma$. Here $0 = t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_{k-1} < t_k = t$ are such that $V|_{[t_{i-1}, t_i]}$ is smooth for $i=1, \ldots, k$. Thus $V'$ can have a finite number of jump discontinuities, so $V''$ may fail to be defined at the $t_i$, but this does not affect the definition of $I_t (V, V)$ above. [Note that I have taken the liberty of replacing do Carmo's non-standard convention for the Riemann curvature tensor with the standard one. That is, $V'' + R(V, \gamma') \gamma' = 0$ is the Jacobi equation.]

One of the confusing things about Section 11.2 of the book is that do Carmo has two *different* subdivisions of $[0, a]$, which are given the same notation. The first one $0 = t_0 < \cdots < t_k = t$ in the previous paragraph, which depends on $V \in \mathcal V(0,t)$, gives the expression for $I_t (V,V)$ for a piecewise smooth vector field $V$ along $\gamma|_{[0,t]}$ that has discontinuities in $V'$ at the $t_j$. Then, in order to study the index of the quadratic form $I_t$, do Carmo introduces a new subdivision $0 = t_0 < \cdots < t_k = a$ (depending only on the geodesic $\gamma$, and not on any particular $V$) such that each $\gamma_{[t_{i-1}, t_i]}$ is minimizing on $[t_{i-1}, t_i]$ with no conjugate points. This is fine (I might have used different notation to make it clear that this is something different, although they will coincide a bit further below.) Let us fix this decomposition once and for all.

Given this subdvision, earlier in Section 11.2 of the book, do Carmo proves that $\mathcal V(0,t) = \mathcal V^+(0,t) \oplus \mathcal V^-(0,t)$, where $V^-(0,t)$ is the subspace consisting of those elements of $\mathcal V(0,t)$ such that $V|_{[t_{i-1}, t_i]}$ is a Jacobi field, for all $i = 1, \ldots, k$. [In fact, do Carmo write $V|_{(t_{i-1} t_i)}$ is a Jacobi field for all $i$, but I think he must mean the closed interval $[t_{i-1}, t_i]$ in order to make sense of the isomorphism $F_t \colon \mathcal V^-(0,t) \to S_j$ defined in the next paragraph. Please let me know if I am wrong.] The space $\mathcal V^-(0,t)$ is clearly finite-dimensional. The space $\mathcal V^+(0,t)$ is the subspace consisting of those elements of $\mathcal V(0,t)$ that vanish at the $t_i$. I understand the proof that $\mathcal V(0,t) = \mathcal V^+(0,t) \oplus \mathcal V^-(0,t)$.

We're almost at the place where I get confused. [Thanks for your patience up to now!] Fix a $t \in (0,a)$. We want to study the quadratic form $I_t$. We can without loss of generality choose the (second) decomposition above (the one that depends only on $\gamma$) so that $t_{j-1} < t < t_j$ for some $j$. Note that since he now restricts $I_t$ to $\mathcal V^-(0,t)$, whose elements are smooth except at the $t_i$, the first $j$ elements of the two decompositions $0 = t_0 < \cdots < t_{j-1} < t$ described above are now in fact the same.

Since $\gamma|_{[t_{i-1}, t_i]}$ has no conjugate points, any Jacobi field along $\gamma|_{[t_{i-1}, t_i]}$ is uniquely determined by its boundary values. Thus, for $t \in (t_{j-1}, t_j)$, the map
$$F_t \colon \mathcal V^-(0,t) \to T_{\gamma(t_1)} M \oplus \cdots \oplus T_{\gamma(t_{j-1})} M =: S_j$$
given by
$$F_t (V) = (V(t_1), \ldots, V(t_{j-1}))$$
is a linear isomorphism, so for $t \in (t_{j-1}, t_j)$ we can regard $I_t$ as a quadratic form on the *fixed* vector space $S_j$, which has dimension $n(j-1)$, where $n=\dim M$. This is all fine.

Now do Carmo says: "since the elements of $V^-(0,t)$ are broken Jacobi fields, it follows from (2) that $I_t$ depends continuously on $t \in (t_{j-1}, t_j)$." (Equation (2) is what I call $(\star)$ above.) I am trying to parse this statement and justify it. [I certainly believe it.] First, we are regarding all the $I_t$ for $t \in (t_{j-1}, t_j)$ as quadratic forms on $S_j$. Then, I believe, continuity of $I_t$ in $t$ should be the same as $t \mapsto I_t(v,v)$ is continuous in $t$ for each fixed $v \in S_j$. By the definition of $\mathcal V^-(0,t)$, we know that $V = F_t^{-1} (v)$ is a Jacobi field on each $[t_{i-1}, t_i]$, so $V'' + R(V, \gamma') \gamma' = 0$, and the first term in $(\star)$ vanishes, so we have only the second term in $(\star)$. For $v \in S_j$ fixed, if $t \in (t_{j-1}, t_j)$ is varied, then $F_t^{-1} (v)$ can only possibly change on $[t_{j-1}, t]$. This means that $V(t_j)$ and $V'(t_j^-)$ are also unchanged, and only $V'(t_j^+)$ can change.

**So my question is this:** Why does $V'(t_j^+)$ vary continuously with $t \in (t_{j-1}, t_j)$, where $V|_{[t_{j-1}, t_j]}$ is the unique Jacobi field along $\gamma|_{[t_{j-1}, t_j]}$ satisfying: $V(t_j)$ is a fixed given vector, and $V(t) = 0$. It seems that I need continuous dependence of $V'$ on the boundary values of $V$, but the "boundary point" $t \in (t_{j-1}, t_j)$ is moving.

Possibly this is all completely trivial and I am missing something obvious. In fact, I hope that is the case. Thanks for reading through all of this!